# Removing multi valued data from a table after normalization

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization

After going through guides for normalization, I have tables in what I believe are 4th normal form here below. These attributes were decomposed from one large table (student number, club, club cost, nickname etc). The problem is I still have repeating rows in STUDENT_CLUB_LIST and STUDENT_NAMES, and I get an error for repeating the primary key or entering redundant data.

From tutorials I've seen, repeating the primary key row is allowed even up to 4NF (for example if student number 100 attends two clubs, there would be two rows) so what am I missing? How can I avoid repeating multivalued attributes if I've already decomposed the attributes into small tables with unique keys.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_CLUB_LIST(

        StudentNumber       Int         NOT NULL,
        Club                Char(25)    NOT NULL,

        CONSTRAINT      StudentNumberPK     PRIMARY KEY (StudentNumber)
                            
                        );
                        

CREATE TABLE CLUB_COST(

        Club            Char(25)            NOT NULL,
        ClubCost        Int                 NOT NULL,
        
        CONSTRAINT      ClubPK              PRIMARY KEY(Club)
        
                        );

CREATE TABLE STUDENT_NAMES(

        StudentNumber       Int         NOT NULL,
        Nickname            Char(25)    NOT NULL,
        
        CONSTRAINT          StudentNamesPK      PRIMARY KEY(StudentNumber)
);
```

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & you have shown no research or other effort at actually answering the question you pose. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook or other authoritative reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs

Comment: What is your exact question--input & goal? PS There are many misconceptions & confusions here. "repeating the primary key row" makes no sense. "multivalued attributes" doesn't mean "repeating [sub]rows" & neither is a problem per se. 4NF is about multivalued dependencies. CKs matter, PKs don't. PS Normalizing a large table is not a good way to start designing. PS Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow multiple rows per `StudentNumber` in `STUDENT_CLUB_LIST`, as well as multiple rows per `Club`. This is the way the many-to-many table works. Each pairing of student and club gets its own row.

You do this by making a **compound primary key** consisting of both columns that reference the other tables. That way each pairing of a given student in a given club is stored just once. But a given student may belong to multiple clubs, and a given club may have multiple student members.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_CLUB_LIST(

    StudentNumber       Int         NOT NULL,
    Club                Char(25)    NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (StudentNumber, Club)
                        
);
```

Comment: You make a compound key. Other factors might determine whether it, or a surrogate, were PRIMARY - or indeed UNIQUE